# Exclude methods from @ModelAttribute in @RestControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller-advice

I have the following controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/{brand}"
public class CarController {

  @GetMapping
  public List<Car> getCars(@PathVariable("brand") String brand) {
    // Some implementation
  }

  @GetMapping("/{model}")
  public Car getCar(@PathVariable("model") String model) {
    // Some implementation
  }

  @PostMapping("/{model}")
  public Car addCar(@PathVariable("model") String model), @RequestBody Car car) {
    // Some implementation
  }
}
```

And the following `RestControllerAdvice`:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = {CarController.class})
public class InterceptModelPathParameterControllerAdvice {

  @Autowired
  CarService carService;

  @ModelAttribute
  public void validateModel(@PathVariable("model") String model) {
    if (!carService.isSupportedModel(model)) throw new RuntimeException("This model is not supprted by this application.");
  }
}
```

The `validateModel` correctly validates the `getCar` and `addCar` methods, but it also validates the `getCars` method. The `getCars` method does not have a `{model}` `@PathVariable`, so a request to this endpoint will always result in a `RuntimeException`.

Is there any way to exclude a method from being impacted by a `ControllerAdvice` and `ModelAttribute` combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have found, there is no *real* way to exclude a method from being intercepted by the `@ModelAttribute` in a `@ControllerAdvice`. You can, however, change the method parameter from `@PathVariable("model") String model` to `HttpServletRequest request` and change the implementation as follows:

```java
@ModelAttribute
public void validateModel(HttpServletRequest) {
  Map<String, String> requestAttributes = (Map<String, String>) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
  if (requestAttributes.containsKey("model") {
    String model = requestAttributes.get("model");
    if (!carService.isSupportedModel(model)) throw new RuntimeException("This model is not supprted by this application.");
  }
}
```